# Connected App In Managed Package with Different Call-back URLs

Tags: rest-api, managed-package, integration, connected-apps, callback

We are working on an composite AppExchange Application.  Which uses connected app to connect to Salesforce from the composite (external) App. As the composite (external) app has different call-back URLs for different Salesforce instance and different Customers, it was not possible to use a single connected app which can reside in a central org (free dev org), and use the same (single) connected app for all subscribers to connect to their SF org. Due to that a manual configuration was added to configure a connected app per customer Salesforce org.  Below is the basic representation of the same.
[image]

**Question:**
Above process is working fine but it involves some manual efforts on customer orgs (setup connected app) every time when a user installs the App in Sandbox, Production, Trial orgs.

One possible solution will be to use a single connected app in a central org with a call-back URL of a middleware page. And middleware page will handle the redirection to different call-back URLs.

Other than a middleware page to handle multiple call-back URLs, is there any other way through which we can make connected app configuration easy for every new App subscriber?

Comment: We actually use a separate connected app per "brand" of the app, since the user is presented with the connected app's name during login and permission grant (at least with OAuth web flow). By sharing the same one, every org will see the same name, even though they have different apps.

Comment: @PhilW, for our application we have a single "brand' of app, which all customers (Subscribes) can connect. The tricky part is the composite (external) app allows custom sub domains as mentioned in diagram. Due to that for a single branding of app also, we can have different call back (redirection) URLs.  That is the reason, we have "Connected App Setup" as a manual step where customer specific call-back URL can be configured. To make this process smooth, we may need a single connected app with a middleware page, which can handle multiple domain redirection.